# Trigger to fire lambda function after a s3 object is created sometimes returns NoSuchKey error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a setup where when a user uploads a file to a s3 bucket a lambda function triggers and does some processing on that file.

The issue I have here sometimes after an upload I get a NoSuchKey error thrown. I have tried uploading the same file multiple times and sometimes it works fine with the expected response and sometimes not.

Could this be the lambda function trying to grab the file without it being fully uploaded? or is it because the function times out?

```
import {
  S3Client,
  GetObjectCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('Event -'+JSON.stringify(event));
  const s3Client = new S3Client({
      region: process.env.REGION, 
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },});


  // Read the object.
  const { Body } = await s3Client.send(
    new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
      Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key
    })
  );
  console.log(await Body.transformToString());
}
```

And here is the sample of the NoSuchKey error thrown -

```
{
    "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
    "errorMessage": "The specified key does not exist.",
    "name": "NoSuchKey",
    "$fault": "client",
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 404,
        "requestId": "FJ4VQ3NWCX5TKPJB",
        "extendedRequestId": "EPS8NoiKhdjQdPEWUvC4mtyOYwMAKzLoaglVEeZPZz/G5ZCViAZ0eV4AekjPTIs0k/GUL6peTME=",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "Code": "NoSuchKey",
    "Key": "Parts+List.txt",
    "RequestId": "FJ4VQ3NWCX5TKPJB",
    "HostId": "hostId",
    "message": "The specified key does not exist.",
    "stack": [
        "NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.",
        "    at de_NoSuchKeyRes (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:6082:23)",
        "    at de_GetObjectCommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:4327:25)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:14:20",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:58:20",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:25:20)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The key is encoded, you'll need to decode it with something like [`decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " ")) `](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html#with-s3-tutorial-create-function-code)

Comment: @AnonCoward my code works. The issue I have is intermittent.

Comment: The error message says that an object with a Key of `Parts+List.txt` does not exist. Does it exist? Or is it called `Parts List.txt`? If it has a space, then you should use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode it or, at the very least, do what @AnonCoward suggests.

Comment: Did you try to use this solution?  It has solved this _exact_ issue for me and others in the past, and I see no reason why it wouldn't work here.